# Python 3.x: Pandas Dataframe How do we change the column names for a specific range?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large csv file that I am reading using pandas. The following is a fraction of how my data looks like. The column names are 0,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18.

```
0   4   6   8   10  12  14  16  18
-2  4500    4500    4500    4500    4500    4500    4500    4500
-1  4650    4650    4650    4650    4650    4650    4650    4650
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

If I use Data.columns, I can change the column names. However, I only want to change a part of the column name. For instance I want to change the column 6,8,10 to bird,dog,strawberry,kiwi,tree,chocolate, and snow respectively.

```
0   4   bird    dog strawberry  kiwi    tree    chocolate   snow
-2  4500    4500    4500    4500    4500    4500    4500    4500
-1  4650    4650    4650    4650    4650    4650    4650    4650
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

How would you write a code? Remember that I have a massive file and want to do a large scale change for many numbers of columns. So I will need efficient line of code for this...

Thanks!

Edit: I meant to express that I desire to change column names starting from the third column.

Comment: you can create a dictionary and use `rename`: `data.rename(columns={6:'bird', 8:'dog', 10:'strawberry'})`

Comment: Hi @Chris, I added an edit.

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? Do want to rename columns in a range? Do you want to change all the column names from column location 3 onwards?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to change the column names from column location 3 and onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to rename all the columns from 3 onwards you can use `zip` to create a dict then rename:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,9), columns=[0,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18])

# create a dict using zip from df.columns[2:]
d = dict(zip(df.columns[2:].values, ['bird','dog','strawberry','kiwi','tree','chocolate','snow']))

# rename you columns
df = df.rename(columns=d)

          0         4      bird       dog  strawberry      kiwi      tree  \
0 -0.121085  1.263364 -0.008604 -0.240872    1.433633  0.092023 -0.903776   
1  0.570377  0.565611 -1.107842  1.498852   -0.655996 -1.215298  0.639862   
2  0.367796 -1.357311 -0.106241 -0.824072    1.055168  0.862952  0.475000   
3  0.945560  0.359249 -0.282965  0.230909   -2.278477  1.656094 -0.031756   
4 -0.611121 -0.159064 -0.711482  2.342169    0.044782 -0.955120  1.481766   

   chocolate      snow  
0   0.607185  0.694980  
1  -0.666239  0.208806  
2   0.018151 -0.656670  
3  -0.438527  0.678592  
4   1.035624  0.537486
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

example_list = [
    {'name' : 'a',
    'age' : 2,
    'gender' : 'm'},
    {'name' : 'b',
    'age' : 5,
    'gender' : 'm'
    }]
df = pd.DataFrame(example_list)
print(df)

df.rename(columns = {'name':'First Name'}, inplace = True)
print(df)
```

Output

```
   age gender name
0    2      m    a
1    5      m    b

   age gender First Name
0    2      m    a
1    5      m    b
```

EDIT:

```
import pandas as pd

example_list = [
    {
        0 : 'a',
        4 : 2,
        6 : 'm'},
    {
        0 : 'b',
        4 : 5,
        6 : 'm'
    }]
df = pd.DataFrame(example_list)
print(df)

df.rename(columns = {0:'apple', 4 : 'bannana', 6 : 'pear'}, inplace = True)
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
   0  4  6
0  a  2  m
1  b  5  m

apple  bannana pear
0    a      2    m
1    b      5    m
```

Comment: I just copy and pasted into my ide and it works fine. I edited my question to show output and indented my import statement. Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: Hi @SlurpGood, yes the code works as it is. I also added an edit to my post. Any ideas on how to write a code that calls the column by the column number for a large scale change?

Comment: I added an example using number based column names, as well if you are importing from csv you can set column names in the pandas.read_csv(columns).